# Passing arguments to function in remapping

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, functions, command

I have the following solution in my `.vimrc` that allows me to wrap text with certain delimiters that works

```
function! Wrap(action, delim)
    let l:delims = {'(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}', '"': '"', "'": "'"}
    if a:action == "w"
        return "c" . a:delim . "\<C-r>" . '"' . get(delims, a:delim) . "\<C-c>"
    elseif a:action == "d"
        return "vi" . a:delim . "c" . "\<BS>" . "\<Del>" . "\<Esc>" . "p" 
    endif
endfunction

xnoremap <expr> w( Wrap("w", "(")
nnoremap <expr> wd( Wrap("d", "(")

xnoremap <expr> w[ Wrap("w", "[")
nnoremap <expr> wd[ Wrap("d", "[")

xnoremap <expr> w{ Wrap("w", "{")
nnoremap <expr> wd{ Wrap("d", "{")

xnoremap <expr> w" Wrap("w", '"')
nnoremap <expr> wd" Wrap("d", '"')

xnoremap <expr> w' Wrap("w", "'")
nnoremap <expr> wd' Wrap("d", "'")
```

I would, however, like to change this so that I can instead have one remapping for wrapping visually selected text and only one other remapping for removing surrounding delimiters. For example:

```
xnoremap <expr> w (pass arguments and call Wrap())
nnoremap <expr> wd (pass arguments and call Wrap())
```

I would then only need to press `w (` on visually selected text to wrap it with `()`, or `wd (` to remove the surround parenthesis from where the cursor is.

I can't seem to find the best way of doing this. I have tried with user-commands, but without success. Is there a way to do this?

I know that some plugins will solve this, but would like to try without plugins.

Comment: If you're ok with an extra `<CR>` keystoke, you can use `input()` in `Wrap` to get the argument

Comment: Thanks @Hoblovski, that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Those are *mappings*, not "remappings".
2. You can use `:help getcharstr()` to, well… get one character from the user:

   ```
   xnoremap <expr> <key> Wrap("w", getcharstr())
   nnoremap <expr> <key> Wrap("d", getcharstr())
   ```

A few comments, though,

- Make sure you experiment with the various possible values of `[expr]` in `getcharstr([expr])`.
- Mapping `wd<char>` in normal mode will make the following harder than necessary:

  - `w` to move to next word,
  - `w` to move to next word, then `d(` to delete from the cursor to the beginning of the sentence,
  - `w` to move to next word, then `d{` to delete from the cursor to the beginning of the paragraph,
  - `w` to move to next word, then `d'<char>` to delete from the cursor to the given mark.

  If I were you I would reconsider my normal mode mapping. Surround, the plugin you are trying to replicate, uses mappings that don't conflict with regular commands. That is a best practice that is not reserved to plugin developers:

  - Surround's visual mode `S` would be the equivalent of your visual mode `w`,
  - and Surround's normal mode `ds` would be the equivalent of your normal mode `wd`.

  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/1f93db9dc976ba851bbb) for mapping ideas.

Comment: FWIW in case `getcharstr()` is unavailable e.g. on vim <=8.1, you can use `nr2char(getchar())`.

Comment: Thanks for the insights @romainl. I have also changed some of the mappings to not clash with other commands.